# How does numerical simulation of GR work in the case of closed timelike curves?

Tags: general-relativity, computational-physics, simulations, closed-timelike-curve

In all cases I'm aware about so far, when you want to do a numerical simulation of a physical system, you invoke the initial conditions and program how the system evolves in time.

Now presumably, I would think the same applies for simulating dynamical spacetime with energy-mass, although admittedly it is a much trickier because I imagine you would have to choose some foliation of spacetime by spacelike hypersurfaces. So naively, I would think the process goes as follows:

1. Specify the initial conditions (metric + stress-energy-mass distribution) on the initial hypersurface.
2. Implement the differential equations for Einstein's equation + geodesic equations + anything else necessary.

Suppose you were numerically simulating a spacetime that contained closed timelike curves and your initial condition consisted of a spacelike hypersurface that occurred before the CTC. Would we be able to run the simulation "forward" in "time" without problems? How exactly would the CTC come into existence? Loosely speaking, it seems like there is some sort of bootstrap paradox at play. (I understand that spacetimes with CTCs have unphysical features and requirements.)

What I am specifically wondering is, is the existence of the CTC determined by the initial conditions on the hypersurface that came before the CTC? What would a numerical simulation show?

(Note that I'm not just interested in simulating geodesics on a predetermined spacetime. I am thinking about a simulation that computes the spacetime metric along the foliations in time as well. This seems very non-trivial to me.)

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle

Comment: If you run the simulation by coordinate time t you'll be in trouble, but if you evaluate the test particle's trajectory over the proper time τ you will be ok since the closed loop occurs in coordinate time while the proper time simply increases

Comment: @Yukterez The complication is that I am imagining that you are simulating both the spacetime (by going through a time-ordered foliation) and the particles. Presumably that would require me to use coordinate time for a given choice of coordinates. I doubt anyone has done such a simulation (they have better things to do like simulating gravitational waves which are physically realizable), but I am wondering what would it be like to attempt this in principle. (In particular, what troubles would you come across?)

Comment: For the [Gödel metric](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/01.html#plot) that has been done already